# Rendering Partials Error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, partials, renderpartial

I'm following a tutorial to create a follow feature for users.  The tutorial creates separate links to view the users' followers and following.  I, however, would like for these to be displayed on the user's profile page and not redirected to another page.

I thought I could accomplish this with a partial so I created _show_follow.html.erb in the user view with this simple code:

```
<h3><%= @title %></h3>
```

I tried to render it with this code in my user show view:

```
<%= render 'show_follow' %>
```

This does not work.  I tested it with static code which works fine, so I'm assuming my problem is in the User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, 
                                        :following, :followers]
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end

def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render '_show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render '_show_follow'
  end
```

Can someone please guide me on the best/least sloppy way to accomplish this?  I'm stuck.  Thanks a million!

Comment: `@title` is not defined in `show.html.erb`, so it wouldn't be defined in the partial. How are you trying to call the `following` and `followers` actions of the `UsersController`?

Comment: In the tutorial, this is how they are calling the following and followers actions...
'<% if @users.any? %>
        <div class="user_avatars">
          <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
          <% end %>'
but they don't use a partial, they created a view show_follow.  I thought I'd make it a partial instead since I don't want it to go to a separate page. Sorry if that doesn't make sense, I'm really confused.